# Dequeing HeaderView in dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier complains about IBoutlet

Tags: objective-c, uiview, header, tableview

I have created a custom UIView that I want to use as the Header Section View of a TableView.
So I manually created a NIB with a UIView component. 
Then I manually created a *.m and *.h for the class that I want to associate with that class, 
"AssignmentHeaderView.m" and "AssignmentHeaderView.h" and I set the Class of the NIB to "AssignmentHeaderView". 
In addition I create a "view" property in the AssignmentHeaderView.h as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view;
```

and  I made the connection between this "view" property and the the"View" in Interface Builder.

Then in my TableViewController, I registered this Nib as a HeaderView in ViewDidLoad with:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AssignmentHeaderView" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"AssignmentHeaderView"];
```

so that I later could dequeue this header view inside the "viewForHeaderInSection" delegate as follows:

```
AssignmentHeaderView *headerView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"AssignmentHeaderView"];
```

But I get an exception error on this line with the following message:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

So the error is complaining that there is no "view" property in the AssignmentHeaderView, when the NIB is unarchived, i think this is what is saying. But I did set the "view" property in AssignmentHeaderView.h , so I don't understand why i get this error.

Any help is much appreciated.

-Malena

Answer (score 6):

For general knowledge, I found the problem. 
The "dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier" tableView method expects that the instance being dequeued is of class type: UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

Since I was trying to use a custom UIView subclass, the compiler wasn't happy. I can only speculate as why instead of telling me that the class of the view I am dequeing should be of type UITableViewHeaderFooterView, it was giving me a NIB loading error. 
But in any case, someone had posted a good solution for how to create a Header Section custom view using UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

Here it is: 
http://iosdev12.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-set-custom-section-header-in.html

this worked for me